# How to start developing Mozilla Firefox addons?

Tags: firefox, programming-languages, firefox-addon

Guide me on the **appropriate technologies to learn to start developing Mozilla firefox addons** & later addons for Songbird & Thunderbird.

What all technologies and softwares are needed. I use ubuntu 9.10 64 bit.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions

Comment: Similar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772/how-do-i-write-a-firefox-addon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which type of addons?

1. Extensions: JavaScript and XUL.
   You can get started [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension).
2. Plugins: NPAPI, the Gecko Plugin API.
   You can read the complete guide [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference).

There is a nice [wizard](http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/extensionwiz/) for generating extension skeletons.

Basiclly, if you are using this wizard, you will need to know primarly JavaScript.

Comment: Like I want to add a item in right click context menu which "adds current page to GOOGLE BOOKMARKS".

Comment: So you want to write an extension. Read the article in my first link and use the wizard to generate a skeleton. Then you will need some basic JavaScript to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to start is to go the Mozilla Extensions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions) page and see what interests you.

For building addons (called Extensions on Mozilla) you can see the page here (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension) where it shows you in details how to create a Hello World extension.

There's an extensive tutorial here: http://www.rietta.com/firefox/index.html

For more, visit Mozilla Extension page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to write a Firefox extension, here's a post on mozilla's blog about that : [How to develop a Firefox extension](http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/)

Maybe this tutorial can help, too : [How to create Firefox extensions](http://roachfiend.com/archives/2004/12/08/how-to-create-firefox-extensions/) *(It's a bit old, though...)*

Answer (score 0):

[**JetPack**](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/) might be of interest if you want to get some quick and dirty implementations using nothing but JavaScript and some CSS rules.