# Suggestions on where to start learning how to make Firefox Plugins?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I haven't had any experience on building plugins, need guidance on where to start, specifically for Firefox.

Comment: There's a huge difference between Firefox extensions, and plugins (both called Add-ons). Extensions are for extending existing functionality, but plugins are stuff like Java, or Adobe Reader.

Comment: So if i want to build a chat application for the browser which has the capability to code such functionality? a plug-in or extension?

Comment: i think in this case you can use both, but i wouzld go for the extension which is easier to handle

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772/how-do-i-write-a-firefox-addon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [this (tutorial)](http://lifehacker.com/264490/how-to-build-a-firefox-extension) and/or [that(XUL references)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_School).

Answer (score 1):

Robert Nyman's talk "How to write your first extension" helped me a lot. You'll find it http://presentation-slides.googlecode.com/files/how-to-write-your-first-extension-berlin.pdf.