# Tutorial for Simplistic Firefox Addon

Tags: firefox-addon, screen-scraping, xpi

Anyone know of a short tutorial where I can build a simplistic Firefox addon?

I'm needing to see how to:

- build the XPI file
- make it have an on/off toggle menu
- when on, make it login to a site, wait until done, and then scrape the main page after login. So, it would involve a form post and mouse click, and then a screen scrape.
- save the screen scrape to a file on the computer

Additionally, this site I'm interacting with has AJAX to build the content on the fly. So, a view source of the HTML only shows Javascript. But after the page is loaded, if I do a select all and then view source, I get a different content than view source. So, I'm hoping the FF addon can see what the browser displays.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772/how-do-i-write-a-firefox-addon will give you some good places to get started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert Nyman's talk "How to write your first extension" helped me a lot. You'll find it at https://web.archive.org/web/20160728010325/http://presentation-slides.googlecode.com/files/how-to-write-your-first-extension-berlin.pdf.