# How to make a Firefox Add-on

Tags: c#, c++, firefox-addon

I hope I can get some jumpstart here on development on Mozilla (Firefox).

I have written a C++ BHO that interacts with IE and I have written a C# application that interacts with ... IE too. Now, I want to port my plugin and my application on Firefox. Can anyone share their wisdoms here? Are there any document that would allow me to jump start on this process? Anyone who has done similar (porting their app from IE to Firefox), I would greatly appreciate their advice on what I should watch for.

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you read this already? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772/how-do-i-write-a-firefox-addon

Answer (score 4):

Unlike Internet Explorer, developing an Extension in Firefox is relatively painless and has excellent documentation. I'd recommend starting at the [MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension).

Firefox uses Javascript and XUL for development. Firebug will be your friend on this.

Comment: +1 though unfortunately, having written a C# BHO and a firefox extension, I can say from experience that it's not so much a matter of *"porting"* usually as it is *"rewriting"* :(

Comment: @BlueRaja - Danny Pflughoeft: Yes, I agree. However Extensions for other browsers like Chrome allow more portability with code from Firefox.

Comment: Is there no way to write a Firefox Add-on in C++ or C ?

Comment: @NiklasR It's possible using the [NPAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI). They are discouraged because often times they are not platform independent and they are considerably more difficult to write.