# Does Mozilla Fennec supports Addons in Mobile Platform?

Tags: mobile, add-on, fennec

Looking if Fennec supports Addons compatibility in Mobile Platforsm like iOs for iphone, Android or Windows.

Also looking forward for guidelines to develop extensions development to use it in Fennec for mobile platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Fennec supports add-ons. In general, you develop you add-on just like for the desktop Firefox: [How do I write a Firefox Addon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772/how-do-i-write-a-firefox-addon)

There are currently two Fennec variants around. The "old" one uses a XUL-based user interface and multiple processes. Here is a [good entry point](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2009/05/resources-for-fennec-add-on-developers/) if you are looking for documentation.

The "new" one uses a native Android user interface - it will soon replace the XUL-based variant on the mobile phones, tablets should follow a bit later. It uses a single process like the desktop Firefox. There is very little documentation at the moment, it's mostly [this text](http://starkravingfinkle.org/blog/2011/11/firefox-android-add-ons-in-a-native-world/).