# Firefox extension .xpi file structure: description, contents, creation, and installation

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

I put a lot of stuff in searching an easy way to develop a Firefox extension, but I am unable to create an extension. Kindly tell me the file structure of Firefox extensions and an easy way to install the extension.

Comment: That depends. Light (restartless) or heavy (XUL) extension? And what is it supposed to do exactly? Inject JS into every page? Modify the UI? The way it is, your question is way too broad.

Comment: Actually I have to inject some js onto  an specific site. I have created a chrome extension in which only two main file is required(manifest.json and background.js), by using this file i am able to inject my background.js script into my site. And now i am searching this kind of injection in firefox. Thanks

Comment: If you want to do it like chrome, very simple, then addon sdk is the way to go. You have to use a page-worker: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker  (go salman khan!)

Comment: Still I am unable to understand how to make .xpi file to upload extension. Will you please elaborate the process to make .xpi file and also required file and there structure. Thanks for you cooperation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to develop Firefox extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409349/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-develop-firefox-extension)

Comment: @roushankumarSingh join up on irc and i can walk you through it. Im on the extdev channel heres mibbit link: https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.mozilla.org%2F%extdev my name is noida on there

Comment: But here is the basic structure for a bootstrap addon, this includes a .xpi file of it too: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9025999 and comment on gist is like a readme, its useful.

Answer (score 9):

### [`.xpi` file format](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPI) ([Extension Packaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Extension_Packaging))

The `.xpi` files that are used as containers for Mozilla (Firefox, Thunderbird, etc.) extensions are merely zip archives that have had the file extension changed to `.xpi` with the files added to the archive using either "deflate" compression, or uncompressed. If you use any other type of compression, other than "deflate", or "store" (uncompressed), you will get an error like:

```
This add-on cannot be installed because it appears to be corrupted
```

The files start in the root directory of the zip compressed archive (i.e. there is *not* an empty first level directory which then contains the files).

The contents of the archive could be only a few files to any number of files. The files that *must* be included depend on the type of add-on which you are packaging. If you are planning on using the [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK), then you probably don't need to know the format for these files, as much of it is abstracted by using the `jpm` tool. If you have no idea what I am talking about, you may want to read up on the [different types](https://web.archive.org/web/20170910014948/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firefox-addon/3235/getting-started-with-firefox-addon/13574/introduction#t=201709100149489262324) of [add-ons for Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) ([WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions), [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK), [Bootstrap/Restartless](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions), and [Overlay/Legacy/XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions)).

#### WebExtensions:

At a minimum, you will have a *manifest.json* file which describes the extension. You will, almost certainly, have additional files. The *chrome.manifest*, *install.rdf*, and *package.json* files used in other types of add-ons are *not used* in WebExtension add-ons. You should *not* have those files.

#### Add-on SDK:

The *.xpi* file for a Firefox Add-on SDK extension should be created by executing [`jpm xpi`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#jpm_xpi). Add-on SDK extensions are described in a *package.json* file. When you run `jpm xpi` your add-on is translated to being a Bootstrap/Restartless add-on.  This is done by translating the *package.json* file into a *install.rdf*, creating a *chrome.manifest* file and adding some wrappers to the JavaScript. You should not try to perform this process yourself, unless doing so is necessary for your add-on to function (which would be quite rare).

#### Bootstrap/Restartless and Overlay/legacy:

At a minimum, you have [*install.rdf*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests), and [*chrome.manifest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration) files.  Bootstrap/Restartless add-ons will also have a *bootstrap.js* file. There will almost always be additional files. These types of add-ons do not use a *package.json*, nor a *manifest.json*.

My very simple Bootstrap/Restartless extension, [Print Button is Print](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/print-button-is-print/?src=api) (changes the print button to print instead of print preview), has the following structure:

```
Archive contains:
  bootstrap.js
  chrome/
  chrome/content/
  chrome/content/options.xul
  chrome/skin/
  chrome/skin/printer-typeC128.png
  chrome/skin/printer-typeC32.png
  chrome/skin/printer-typeC48.png
  chrome/skin/printer-typeC64.png
  chrome.manifest
  install.rdf
  license.txt
Total 12 entries (42360 bytes)
```

- There are the required [*install.rdf*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Install_Manifests) and [*chrome.manifest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration) files.
- The file [*bootstrap.js*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) is required for [Bootstrap/Restartless](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Bootstrapped_extensions) extensions. It contains the code that is run when the extension is installed, removed, enabled, disabled, or upon Firefox startup or shutdown.  This extension is simple enough such that all the JavaScript code is contained in *bootstrap.js*.
- There is a file *chrome/content/options.xul* which is a XUL definition of the [options dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Adding_preferences_to_an_extension#Design_the_preference_dialog).
- The *license.txt* just explains that the extension was relased under the [Mozilla Public License, v2.0](http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/).
- The `.png` files are the icon for this extension at various resolutions.

### Creating the *.xpi* file

You can use whatever method you desire to create the *.zip* file, which is renamed to *.xpi*. Keep in mind the requirement that the only compression method that is supported is "deflate", but files can also be added to the archive uncompressed. Your top level files (e.g. which ever you have of *manifest.json* (WebExtensions), or everything else: *chrome.manifest*, and *install.rdf*) should be in the root directory of the archive, not in a subdirectory.

To create the `.xpi` file I use a batch file, which uses a combination of DOS and Unix/Linux (actually [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)) commands:

*mkxpi.bat*:

```
rm -f PrintButtonIsPrint@makyen.foo.xpi
zip -1 -r PrintButtonIsPrint@makyen.foo.xpi * -x@xpi.ignore
pause
```

This removes any old version of the `.xpi` file. It then creates a new `.xpi` file using, `-1`, minimal compression (speed of access is more important than saving space), which forces only storing uncompressed or using "deflate". The new *.xpi* will contain all files and subdirectories `*`, but ignoring all the files in the *xpi.ignore* text file (`-x@xpi.ignore`).  Ignoring files is used because I have other things in the directory (e.g. `.git` directory, `.bak` files auto-created from editor, etc.). Once the `.xpi` file is created the script executes `pause` so I can verify which files were included, that there were no errors, etc., instead of just having the window disappear and assuming that everything is fine.

My *xpi.ignore* file is a bit long, as it accumulates cruft from various projects and is rarely cleaned out:

```
*.com
*.class
*.dll
*.exe
*.o
*.so
*.7z
*.dmg
*.gz
*.iso
*.jar
*.rar
*.tar
*.zip
*.log
*.sql
*.sqlite
*.svg
*/.DS_Store
*/.DS_Store?
*/._*
._*
*/.Spotlight-V100
.Spotlight-V100
*/.Trashes
.Trashes
*/ehthumbs.db
*/Thumbs.db
*.ORIG
*.bak
*OLD*
OLD/*
*/OLD/*
*.OLD
*.OLD[0-9]
*/OLD/*
*/OLD[0-9]/*
*.unknown
*.unknown[0-9]
*.updated
*.updated[0-9]
*/Copy *
*/OLD
*/OLD*
*/OLD[0-9]
*/OLD[0-9][0-9]
*/test/*
*/not in xpi/*
*/tmp
*.tmp
*/foo
*.foo
*checkpoint
.git
*/.git
.gitignore
*/.gitignore
xpi.ignore
mkclean.bat
mkclean.bat.DONTRUN
mkxpi.bat
*.xpi
*/devtools-toolbox-window.ico
*/devtools-webconsole.ico
*/JSConsoleWindow.ico
*/main-window.ico
*/places.ico
*/viewSource.ico
```

### [Installing extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Installing_extensions)

**As normal extensions:**
In order to install an extension as a normal add-on into a branded Release or Beta version of Firefox it must be [signed by Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution). This is done by [submitting it to AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/developers/addon/submit/). You can install unsigned extensions as normal add-ons into other versions of Firefox (e.g. [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/), [Unbranded Beta, or Unbranded Release](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing#Unbranded_Builds)) by setting `xpinstall.signatures.required` to `false` in `about:config`.

If you choose, in a particular installation of Firefox, you can completely disable the add-on signing requirement. For more information, you can see my answer: [How can I disable signature checking for Firefox add-ons?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403531/3773011)

[Installing an extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Installing_extensions) (i.e. the `.xpi` file) can be a simple matter of dragging and dropping it onto a Firefox window running the profile in which you desire it installed. For [development/testing](http://Setting%20up%20an%20extension%20development%20environment), you can have the extension be in a directory on your local drive by using a [Firefox extension proxy file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Setting_up_extension_development_environment#Firefox_extension_proxy_file) (create a file named as the extension's `<em:id>` (in *install.rdf* for Bootstrap/Restartless and Overlay/Legacy) in the profile's *extensions* directory containing one line with the complete path to the directory containing the extension's files). Depending on what your goal is (one profile, all profiles, all users, which OS, etc.), there are other options as to how to [install extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Installing_extensions).

**As [temporary add-ons](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Temporary_Installation_in_Firefox):**
The only type of extension which can not be installed as a temporary add-on is Overlay/Legacy. Such extensions require the browser to be restarted after the install prior to being functional.  As such, they can not be temporary.

To install an extension as a temporary, navigate to `about:debugging`.  From that page, click on Load Temporary Add-on, then navigate popup to the appropriate folder and select either an *.xpi* file, or any file in the directory. If you select a file other than an *.xpi* file, it is assumed that the directory contains unpacked add-on files which will be automatically identified.

Comment: This answer is now outdated and contains dead links. https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/getting-started-with-web-ext/#Automatic_extension_reloading

Answer (score 4):

### Generate a signed .xpi

1. Install web-ext with NPM, maybe you will need root privileges: `npm install --global web-ext`
2. Go to https://addons.mozilla.org/es/developers/addon/api/key/ and generate a new API KEY.
3. Go to your extension folder, open a terminal and execute: `web-ext sign --api-key=$AMO_JWT_ISSUER --api-secret=$AMO_JWT_SECRET` where $AMO_JWT_IUSSER and $AMO_JWT_SECRET are the keys you generated in the previous step.