# How to make simple firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

i wanna make a simple firefox extension that would have some buttons in a panel and buttons clicks opens a webpage.

i know JS and i've maked extension for chrome before but i think making for firefox is alittle harder.

tnx for your help.

Comment: I recommend you to visit this [page](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/06/05/how-to-develop-firefox-extension/). Do you want to make extensions for desktop or for Android Firefox browser? Also, StackOverflow has the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772/how-do-i-write-a-firefox-addon

Comment: Thanks for sharing @albert but that blog entry you linked to is for more advanced developers. For newcomers use this page - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Your_first_WebExtension - While the stuff mentioned by albert still works, and should work in the future, it is harder. The WebExtension way is as easy as Google chrome extensions.